# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php

I have installed WAMP. I am using Tomcat 6 to run my PHP scripts. I am also using JavaBridge.war and I have copied my php scripts into \webapp\JavaBridge\project. 
I have removed the semicolon from php.ini file before the statements

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

I have added C:\wamp\bin into my PATH env variable. I have copied all dll's from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext into C:\windows\system32

I am still getting this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\project\pf_query.php on line 534

I don't get this error when I run my PHP script from Apache 2.2.11 included in the WAMP package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you edit the correct php.ini file?

```
<?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

(executed in the tomcat6 environment) can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this problem, I needed to set the extension_dir variable to point to my php installation.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.