# PHP Error: "Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()"

Tags: mysqli, database-connection, php, apache2.2

In PHP I'm getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

I checked my `php.ini` file and there is no `;` in front of `extension=php_mysql.dll`
or `extension=php_mysqli.dll`.

I think the I am getting this error because my figuration File (php.ini) Path is `C:\Windows`.  How would I change it to `C:\Apache2.2\php\php.ini`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719243/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect)

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu machines you can try:

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

since the basic PHP5 install does not include the `mysqli_connect` function.

Comment: you migth need to restart the apache2 server `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thank you P Mag and @Qualphey! I thought I restarted this a while ago but must have forgot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path using PHPIniDir in .htaccess or your server config.

ie.

```
PHPIniDir "C:/Apache2.2/php"
```

You won't have to recompile PHP if the extension gets loaded correctly (so make sure your extension_dir is correct), just make sure you restart Apache after you made these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile PHP with the extension for this library.

Comment: can you explain that a little more? What do I need to do to recompile?

Comment: Recompilation is not necessary. You can just take binary module and turn it on in php (in dynamic manner).