# MySQL through PHP through Apache on Windows dont work

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation, httpmodule

I am working on a Windows 7(x64) with Apache 2.4 x86, Php54 x86
and MySql 5.6 x64.

- PHP is working well on my Apache Web Server.
- When i run PHP from CommandLine : `php dbTest.php`  it runs without problems
- but when i try to load my page, i get the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in <path to dbtest.php> on line 3`
- tried installing PHP 55 but nothin...
- Tried putting libmysql.dll in (php dir, win/system32, apache bin)
- installed VC71 runtimes (because i saw it in a troubleshooting guide)

Edit:
- also tried installing all x64 (Apache and PHP)
- tried to install Apache v2.2 and PHP v5.3,

Nothing works...

1. how come running the command-line works but through Apache, it isn't working?
2. i see mysqlnd listed, but not mysql/mysqli, as if mysqlnd was the module...

Thank you for your time.
and for saving me the last few hair i have!

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 comes with mysqlnd installed by default so you shouldn't need libmysqli.dll

Does `phpinfo()` list a mysqli block?

Comment: Hmm, does it list `mysqlnd` anywhere?

Comment: though, i try running WordPress server which use `mysqli`

Comment: Try what this thread suggests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705028/php-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect

Answer (score 0):

You need this file in ext directory php_mysqli.dll

Comment: the file `php_mysqli.dll` exist in ext + made sure `extension_dir = "ext"` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` is uncommented