# how to config wamp2's mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql

I setup wamp2, and write some codes to test it.

```
echo mysql_query("localhost", "root", "root");
```

but in web page, it tell me

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in D:\PHP\WWW\mysqltest.php on line 9
```

meanwhile in php.ini i do write

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

but it still dosen't work, 
I know the reason is that I fail to config wamp's mysql server,
is there somebody can tell me how to config?

Comment: What does phpinfo() show? Have your tried mysqli_query?

Comment: use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) !
mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: Did you restart everything after changing the config

Comment: yes, i restart it, but I did not succeed configure mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this and if the connection fails u will get the reason of the error as we are using

*mysqli_error()*

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");
if (!$connection)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
```

for mysql configuration in wamp,have a look at the following link http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Setup_MySQL_in_WAMP_-_password_setting,_service_shutdown_%26_startup

Comment: Still not work! I think it's not the codes problem, instead , it's the wamp's problem! It dosen't offer mysql server,and i can't find someing about mysql in the configuration information

Comment: it should conatin mysql as WampServer is a web development platform on Windows allowing you to create dynamic web applications with Apache2, PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @user2963334 http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Setup_MySQL_in_WAMP_-_password_setting,_service_shutdown_%26_startup

Comment: i prefer xamp over wamp.

Comment: So, please tell me how to config wamp's mysql server?

Comment: i posted a link in 2nd comment of mine.have a look.

Comment: @user2963334 your welcome :) enjoy coding.feel free to except my answer if ur issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to connect to mysql here so It should be  `mysql_connect` not `mysql_query`.

**Note:** `mysql` is deprecated. Use`mysqli` or `PDO` statements.

Comment: Not this problem, even i change it ti mysql_connect, it still tell me that Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect(), so the problem is my wamp2 can't provide mysql server, and i wonder how to do

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719243/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect

Comment: Thanks, I try it <?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'); and get ini: E:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini , is it right?