# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysqli, ssh

My php script from PuTTY on a synology sever returns this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()`.

Mysqli is installed on the server and has been used many times before in scripts via a browser. I don't understand why `mysqli_connect()` is supposedly undefined. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719243/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect)

Answer (score 2):

By running this from CLI (from Putty):
`php70 --ini`
i printed list of ini files used by PHP.

I found, that web server is using
`/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php70/conf.d/user_settings.ini`
while CLI doesn't use that file. It only using
`/usr/local/etc/php70/php.ini`

So, I had to add few lines to that file:
`sudo vi /usr/local/etc/php70/php.ini`

Here are the lines to add:

```
extension = mysqli.so
extension = pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: I'm running php7 with Apache2.4 in windows. getting error as `Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() ` where to add these lines in **php.ini**

Comment: @Shambhu, this question is for Synology OS. I would recommend search / create separate question for Windows

Answer (score 1):

create a php file and have code <?php phpinfo(); ?> check whether mysqli section is displayed or not. It should display the following string in HTML Table format.

mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled

if mysqli is not available, then you need to enable it in php.ini / while configuring with apachee.

Comment: Is it a shared hosting, somebody wud have disabled it accidently .

Comment: Yeah I already did that and mysqli is enabled and o it's not a shared hosting.

Comment: Do this - > Don't know it might be changed i.e., php.ini, Might be a issue in php.ini. It was a simple random syntax error in the /etc/php/php.ini file. Found it after running php -m .     Ref: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152355. Ref 2 : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138131 . Atlast Check "who" the last logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

Web version and CLI version are using different php.ini files.

you can find out which ini file is used by the following command

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

then configure this php.ini to make it support mysqli.